# VB.NET looping through similarly named form controls

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

Ok, I got a tickler for your brains. I am converting a program I wrote in VB6 to Visual Studio 2010 VB.Net and have run into a problem. I am trying to cycle through 20 form elements on a form that all have the prefix 'chkCustomerItems' and then have a number 1 to 20 behind them. I am using this with a database lookup so that it there is a database entry it then applies the database item name to the checkbox's text field and turns visibility on. Here is the code I wrote:
    ConnOpenClose()

```
Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Sql = "SELECT * FROM CustomersItems;"
Rs.Open(Sql, Conn)

If Rs.EOF = False Then
    tempInteger = 1
    Rs.MoveFirst()
    Do
        tempString = "chkCustomerItems" & tempInteger.ToString
        Me.Controls(tempString).Text = Rs.Fields("Item").Value
        Me.Controls(tempString).Visible = True
        tempInteger = tempInteger + 1
        Rs.MoveNext()
        If tempInteger = 21 Then GoTo ExitLoop
    Loop Until Rs.EOF
ExitLoop:
End If
```

When it runs, I get a NullReferenceException error. This is basically the code that I used in VB6 (with some changes for .NET infrastructure). Help me please figure out what I am doing wrong, for the time being I am having to hard code all 20 items in, and while it works, it doesn't look nor run pretty.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using **Text** property so i assume that this is textbox. 
try this:

```
DirectCast(Controls(tempString), TextBox).Text = Rs.Fields("Item").Value
```

Comment: WOW, that is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so very much. I knew there was a code in .NET to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If any of your controls are embedded in any container controls (panels, tabs, etc), you will not be able to get to them through the Controls collection indexing.

Instead, you will need to use Controls.Find with the second parameter (searchAllChildren) set to true (I also added some additional checking and .Net ways of doing things):

```
 Do
    tempString = "chkCustomerItems" & tempInteger.ToString

    Dim aoControls As Control()
    aoControls = Me.Controls.Find(tempString, True)
    If aoControls IsNot Nothing AndAlso aoControls.Length <> 0 Then
       Dim oTextBox As TextBox

       oTextBox = TryCast(aoControls(0), TextBox)
       If oTextBox IsNot Nothing Then
          oTextBox.Text = Rs.Fields("Item").Value
          oTextBox.Visible = True
       End If
    End If

    tempInteger = tempInteger + 1
    Rs.MoveNext()
    If tempInteger = 21 Then 
       Exit Do
    End If
Loop Until Rs.EOF
```

Comment: I put this code in place exactly as you have typed it, however on the line oTextBox = TryCast(aoControls, TextBox), I get the error message "Value of type '1-dimensional array of System.Windows.Form.Control' cannot be converted to 'Ssytem.Windows.Forms.Textbox' at aoControls. - Any ideas why?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. It should be `aoControls(0)`. I have updated the answer.